# Constructor in for loop using API

Tags: javascript, api, loops, for-loop, constructor

So first problem is that I get users not the same order as it is in array. I know it's because others sends back data faster then others but how can I make it to do it in order? Another problem is why for loop loops firstly code in it till second get and after it finish, my code after second get starts working? Here's my code:

```
codepen.io/Vanagasa/pen/zwPNpN
```

Comment: more info please, more code examples, we cannot predict

Comment: Include all relevant code _in the question itself_, not linked to an external site. Read [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question.